# Given a set of time-series data, how would I determine another time-series is a linear combination of the set?

Tags: st.statistics, computer-science, time-series

In other words, determine if sum linear combination of existing time-series could result in the desired time-series. I'm unsure if assumptions about the time-series may clarify the problem better, so feel free to make whatever reasonable assumptions. Apologies if this is a non-sensical question, I don't know much about time-series analysis.

Comment: This Q would be a better fit at https://stats.stackexchange.com/, but you will need to tell us some more context! What does your time-series represent in real life?

Comment: Sounds like a least squares approximation could help. If the desired time series is a column vector $y$ and the existing time series are the columns of a matrix $M$ then solve $M^TM\lambda=M^Ty$ to get coefficients $\lambda$ then look whether that approximation is close enough to the desired or not. Tools like [numpy.linalg.lstsq](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) or `lm` in R can help with computing the coefficients.

Comment: Just make them into a big matrix and compute the SVD.